# Why do I sometimes get different SHA256 hashes in Java and PHP?

Tags: java, php, sha256

So I have an odd little problem with the hashing function in PHP. It only happens some of the time, which is what is confusing me. Essentially, I have a Java app and a PHP page, both of which calculate the SHA256 of the same string. There hasn't been any issues across the two, as they calculate the same hash (generally). The one exception is that every once in a while, PHP's output is one character longer than Java's.

I have this code in PHP:

```
$token = $_GET["token"];
$token = hash("sha256", $token."<salt>");
echo "Your token is " . $token;
```

99% of the time, I get the right hash. But every once in a while, I get something like this (space added to show the difference):

```
26be60ec9a36f217df83834939cbefa33ac798776977c1970f6c38ba1cf92e92 # PHP
26be60ec9a36f217df83834939cbefa33ac798776977c197 f6c38ba1cf92e92 # Java
```

As you can see, they're nearly identical. But the top one (computed by PHP) has one more 0 for some reason. I haven't really noticed a rhyme or reason to it, but it's certainly stumped me. I've tried thinking of things like the wrong encoding, or wrong return value, but none of them really explain why they're almost identical except for that one character.

Any help on this issue would be much appreciated.

EDIT: The space is only in the bottom one to highlight where the extra 0 is. The actual hash has no space, and is indeed a valid hash, as it's the same one that Java produces.

EDIT2: Sorry about that. I checked the lengths with Notepad++, and since it's different than my normal text editor, I misread the length by 1. So yes, the top one is indeed right. Which means that it's a bug in my Java code. I'm going to explore Ignacio's answer and get back to you.

Comment: Actually I don't think PHP is to blame here. Hash function generates a string consisting of hex characters [a-f0-9], but whitespace is certainly not one of them.

Comment: I put a quick edit in there. I only put that space there so people wouldn't have to search for the extra 0. It's actually a valid hash.

Comment: Can you provide sample input that produces this behavior?

Comment: '%the first one%'.length = 64. Erm? Or you just tried to show an example, not a real hash when it went wrong?

Comment: Most of the languages just use a wrapper around an existing library. Not sure in the case of PHP/Java, but could you try it in Python and see if you get a similar result to one of the two? http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html

Comment: What library are you using in Java and what does the code look like? The problem is on the Java side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The top hash is the correct length; the bottom hash is output because the hexadecimal values were not zero-filled on output (note that it's the MSn of a byte). So, a bug in the Java program unrelated to the hash algorithm.

```
>>> '%04x %02x%02x %x%x' % (0x1201, 0x12, 0x01, 0x12, 0x01)
'1201 1201 121'
```

Comment: Sorry, had to downvote you - he already explained the white space in the second set was so that we could identify where the difference was.

Comment: @Duniyadnd: Yes, I accounted for that. My answer explains it.

Comment: @Duniyadnd regardless of that, the second hash cannot possibly be correct: it's only 63 characters.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams guess I misunderstood the what OP was saying - thought the space was replacing the character that was different. Removed the downvote. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: This turned out to be correct. There's a static SHA256 function in our program that uses the Java's MessageDigest. Unfortunately, I took this code from a website a long time ago when it had a bug in it. A quick bitwise operation change and it's all good now. Thanks for the help. Sorry about the misleading hashes. I should have double-checked that length.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's the SECOND hash which seems to have an incorrect length (63). Could it be that it is generated by assembling two different tokens, and maybe the last one - which should be 16 characters - gets the initial zero removed?

Comment: Could be related to PHP's weak typing, detecting that it's a number and "helpfully" removing the 0 at the beginning.

Comment: @BrendanLong The second is actually generated by Java. )

Comment: Can't be /directly/ generated. I find it difficult to believe that Java is getting one sha256 in sixteen wrong, and nobody raises hell about it. Same goes for _GET conversion. I vote @Ignacio's answer.